# Plot a family of circles in 3D

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have the following code for plotting 100 circles in separate height planes where the radius increases from 1 to 100.

```
for r=1:1:100
t=linspace(0,2*pi);
x=r*cos(t);
y=r*sin(t);
for h=100:100:10000   
    z = 100 * r * ones(1, length(t));
    plot3(x,y,z);
    if r == 1 && h == 100
        hold on;
        set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
    end
    drawnow;
end
```

end

Like this: [image]

**Question**

Now I want to change the code in order for the radius to **decrease** from 100 to 1, i.e turn the cone upside down. So the code should probably read like this but i can't get it to work:

```
for r=100:1:1
t=linspace(0,2*pi);
x=r*cos(t);
y=r*sin(t);
for h=100:100:10000   
    z = 100 * r * ones(1, length(t));
    plot3(x,y,z);
    if r == 100 && h == 100
        hold on;
        set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
    end
    drawnow;
end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right. Try this:

```
for r=100:-1:1
```

The syntax is as follows:

```
for i=istart:istride:iend
```

For Optimization try this - i think this is as fast as it gets (tried it out with octave and gnuplot). I think now the script does it job just fine ;-):

```
t=linspace(0,2*pi);             % the array t doesnt get changed during for r=...
z = ones(1, length(t));         % same here: one preallocation should do the job

for r=100:-1:1

x=r*cos(t);
y=r*sin(t);

    z(:) = 10000-r*100;
    plot3(x,y,z);
    if r == 100
        hold on;
    end
    drawnow;

end

set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]); %I think this is the most expesive operation. 
hold off
```

The problem was, that you didn't assume the linear relation between z and r.

Comment: How could I forget that? I'm embarrassed...Thank you.

Comment: The code is however just as before, incredibly  slow. Any idea why?

Comment: @EricAm Check the edit. Try to set those variables which are loop-indipendent outside the loop. Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate your work but It does not actually get it right. If I change r=1:1:100 to r=100:-1:1 in your code it does not produce anything.

Comment: I think you need to edit the hold option: if r==100.

Comment: @EricAm Adapted the if condition. Your code works hilarious... plotting circles all over the place. Now, please give me my check sign back XD

Comment: I have the same code as in your post but are you sure it plots a cone with its top at "the top". Because now it plots the same as my plot above.

Comment: @EricAm Reread your post. No, it doesn't. Will check that in a second.

Comment: @EricAm for a moment I was embarassed. Recheck my Post, will you?

Comment: Looks good! You changed z so I'll look into it. I appreciate it